# Calculate Quartile Based on ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, quartile

I have a dataframe where I am trying to calculate the first quartile (0.25) grouped by an ID in another column.

For example, in the snippet below, I would like to create a new column named Quartile 1 with first quartile (0.25) values for grouped ABC and DEF respectively.

So, all rows with ID 'ABC' would have the same values (likewise for DEF).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'ABC'], 'Values': [57, 72, 88, 43, 61]})
df['Quartile 1'] = 

Index ID    Values  Quartile_1
0     ABC     57    
1     DEF     72    
2     ABC     88    
3     DEF     43    
4     ABC     61
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `transform` + `quantile`

```
df['Quartile_1'] = df.groupby('ID').Values.transform('quantile', q=0.25)

    ID  Values  Quartile_1
0  ABC      57       59.00
1  DEF      72       50.25
2  ABC      88       59.00
3  DEF      43       50.25
4  ABC      61       59.00
```